# RTCVideoTrack shows stretched WebRTC

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, webrtc

I am using core **WebRTC framework** and rendering my local stream in IPhone full screen mode. Unfortunately, my video shows stretched, doesn't show like video view in camera app.

I tried to add aspect ratio in `RTCMediaConstraints` and also used `adaptOutputFormatToWidth` method to fix the output.

```
NSDictionary* mandatoryConstraints;

/* want to calculate aspect ratio dynamically */
NSString *aspectRatio = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",(double)4/3];
if (aspectRatio) {
   mandatoryConstraints = @{ kRTCMediaConstraintsMaxAspectRatio: 
   aspectRatio};
}

RTCMediaConstraints *cameraConstraints = [RTCMediaConstraints alloc];
        cameraConstraints = [cameraConstraints initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints optionalConstraints:nil];


RTCAVFoundationVideoSource *localVideoSource =  [peerFactory avFoundationVideoSourceWithConstraints:mediaConstraint];
        [localVideoSource adaptOutputFormatToWidth:devicewidth:devicewidth fps:30];
```

In below link, the difference between camera video view and my app call video view is shown

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HN3KQcJphtC3VzJjlI4Hm-D3u2E6qmdQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are rendering your video in **RTCEAGLVideoView**, which require adjustment for size, you can use **RTCMTLVideoView** in place of  **RTCEAGLVideoView**.

and if you want to use RTCEAGLVideoView, use RTCEAGLVideoViewDelegate method.

```
- (void)videoView:(RTCEAGLVideoView *)videoView didChangeVideoSize:(CGSize)size;
```

this method will give you correct size of the video.

Answer (score 1):

(For Swift) -> Use **RTCMTLVideoView** and set **videoContentMode**

```
#if arch(arm64)
let renderer = RTCMTLVideoView(frame: videoView.frame)
renderer.videoContentMode = .scaleAspectFill
#else
let renderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: videoView.frame)
#endif
```

Comment: RTCMTLVideoView is old, better using RTCEAGLVideoView